# Use GMP types (mpf_t/mpz_t) as keys in a hashtable

Tags: c, hash, byte, gmp

I need to use GMPs mpf_t/mpz_t as keys in a hashtable.
Is there any efficient way to access the raw bytes of the number representation so I can run a hash function over them?

I already read the documentation but I don't really feel smarter now. ;)

Thanks!
Regards,
Ethon

Comment: Doing that isn't currently supported. There are plans to maybe add a documented API to access the raw representation in a future release. In the meantime, reading the source can help (there are comments!).

Comment: The page [C++ std::hash for GMP's big integer types mpz_class and mpz_t](http://daniel-strecker.com/blog/2020-07-06_c++_hash_for_gmp_mpz_t_mpz_class/#code) might have a solution for you. It provides code for using C++17's built-in data hashing algorithm for `string_view` to hash `mpz_t` and `mpz_class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of curiosity, why use hashing when you can sort by value? Comparison is very quick, as it compares the bytes / limbs from MSB to LSB, returning a result as soon as they differ.

You can access the raw data using the platform-dependent `mp_limb_t` type. Both `mpz_t` and `mpf_t` have an `mp_limb_t` vector stored at the address specified by `_mp_d`, with the number of significant limbs given by the absolute value of the `_mp_size` field. (the definitions are in `gmp.h`)

Of course, if the hash function depends on an 8-bit byte vector, you will need to convert the limb vector. Fortunately, the number of bits in a `mp_limb_t` - `GMP_LIMB_BITS` - is always going to be divisible by 8 on any sane platform.

Comment: Normally only `GMP_NUMB_BITS` bits are relevant per limb and there could easily be a number of nails not multiple of 8. However, nails are unused these days, so it doesn't matter currently.

Comment: what a pointless response...